# gson.toJson() is not working in android 8 and lower devices

Tags: android, gson, android-tv

It is giving the following exception fatal, when application is launching

```
2020-09-28 17:56:22.145 5895-5895/? E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.nagra.uk.jado, PID: 5895
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to resume activity {com.nagra.uk.jado/com.nagra.uk.jado.MainActivity}: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.content.res.ColorStateList declares multiple JSON fields named mChangingConfigurations
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3581)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3621)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2862)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0)
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589)
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106)
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494)
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method)
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438)
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
     Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: class android.content.res.ColorStateList declares multiple JSON fields named mChangingConfigurations
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:172)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.createBoundField(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:117)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.getBoundFields(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:166)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.create(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:102)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.getAdapter(Gson.java:458)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:56)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$1.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:127)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(ReflectiveTypeAdapterFactory.java:245)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.ObjectTypeAdapter.write(ObjectTypeAdapter.java:107)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:97)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.CollectionTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(CollectionTypeAdapterFactory.java:61)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.write(TypeAdapterRuntimeTypeWrapper.java:69)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:208)
        at com.google.gson.internal.bind.MapTypeAdapterFactory$Adapter.write(MapTypeAdapterFactory.java:145)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:704)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:683)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:638)
        at com.google.gson.Gson.toJson(Gson.java:618)
        at com.nagra.uk.jado.MainActivity.sendUpdatedData(MainActivity.java:410)
        at com.nagra.uk.jado.MainActivity.onResume(MainActivity.java:392)
        at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnResume(Instrumentation.java:1355)
        at android.app.Activity.performResume(Activity.java:7117)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.performResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3556)
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleResumeActivity(ActivityThread.java:3621) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2862) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.-wrap11(Unknown Source:0) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1589) 
        at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:106) 
        at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:164) 
        at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:6494) 
        at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Native Method) 
        at com.android.internal.os.RuntimeInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(RuntimeInit.java:438) 
        at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:807)
```

Can anyone help on the same.. The same code is working on Android 9 and other devices

Comment: Read the log:

You have declares multiple JSON fields named mChangingConfigurations

Comment: But I don't have any fields named mChangingConfigurations in my whole android project

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you're trying to serialize a `ColorStateList`. Serializing classes that you don't control is risky, but in this case it doesn't work because it has a field called `mChangingConfigurations` and the abstract base class, `ComplexColor`, also has a field called `mChangingConfigurations`. GSON cannot handle serializing two different fields with identical names, so it fails.

Without knowing your specific use case, my generalized advice would be to avoid serializing classes you don't control. If you need to be able to recreate them from serialized data, then you can serialize the specific data needed to construct them (e.g., the specific color int(s) and state(s)).